# User Impersonation for CakePHP Auth component

Tags: cakephp, authentication

In CakePHP Auth Component it is possible to have admin user (or a group ) to impersonate any user in the system for testing purpose?

Comment: I have a very dirty way to do it, just replace the $_SESSION['Auth']['User'] with the user object I want to impersonate. Of course it is not a good way to do

Answer (score 1):

Really you shouldn't be testing this live anyways. It sounds to me like you want to test logging in and using the site as users other than the admin.

This seems like a perfect case for unit tests. Write a test, mock an auth'ed user object and and run some code as that mocked user. Make a mock user for each access level you use in the site. It will be much more reliable and reproducible.

The manual has some good info on testing - as does the blog http://www.dereuromark.de/ and a quick search on this site brings up a ton of useful hints / techniques.